# Error installing Debian on Virtual_machine(Disk parallel)

Tags: debian, virtual-machines, mac-osx-server

**Debian 12** keeps giving me a new error each time, the last one I got after finishing the installation is:

`ERROR TRYING TO BOOT FROM SATA DRIVE 1`

I tried the open Disk parallel and followed a suggestion - by Expanding Advanced settings drop-down menu and pasting the following system flag:- `vm.bios.efi=1`
but now I got a TOTAL BLACK SCREEN and I'm stuck.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: after finishing the installation of debian on the virtual machine, i got a black screen .
i tried a solution (vm.bios.efi=1)someone suggested but it's not working .

Comment: please provide all i requested. it sounds for me, that you trying to solve a home and enduser problem

Comment: what do you mean by enduser problem . i can't provide many info because all i got is a black screen, what i can provide is what the options i selected before and what is my computer and where/how to install.
i suggest everyone to go for a LiveGnomeNetinstall image(ISO), then make a physical install.
However the challenge i couldn't bypass are how to install Debian on another mac partition, and how to physically install Debian on USB(not bootable thing ) and make it runable on Mac.
i really do want somebody to make a video about it step by step and explain the procedures.